# Can't show icon in input button hover using pseudo class beofre

Tags: html, css

I need show an envelope icon when the user hovers over a button.

I used the pseudo class `before` to show the icon. When I change `opacity` in `.btn-btn-envelope::before` to `1`, I still can't see the envelope icon.

```css
.btn-pos {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.btn-btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: #502030;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Lekton', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90px;
}

.btn-btn-envelope {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-btn-envelope::before {
  content: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1034/1034138.png');
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-btn-envelope:hover {
  text-indent: -20px;
}

.btn-btn-envelope:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-pos">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn-btn btn-btn-envelope">
</div>
```

([*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/ho36vj8b/))

Comment: additionally to duplicate, your picture is black, so it's going to be hard to see it anyways with a black button

Comment: How is this a duplicate the other answer is about jQuery this is all about CSS.

Comment: Here is a solution. Just add icon class to your input then in your CSS add .icon{background-image:url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1034/1034138.png');        background-size: 0;  background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: right;} .icon:hover{background-size: 25px 25px;}

Comment: Check it here. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbPpyO